# How to fix "Set DOTNET_USER_SECRETS_FALLBACK_DIR" error when using docker compose?

Tags: c#, asp.net, docker, docker-compose, docker-secrets

I am using docker-compose to run my asp.net api application. When I use the command "docker-compose up" I receive the error:

```
Could not determine an appropriate location for storing user secrets. Set the DOTNET_USER_SECRETS_FALLBACK_DIR environment variable to a folder where user secrets should be stored.
```

In my yml file I have:

```
version: '3'

services:
  kestrel_apache:
    build: ./
    ports:
      - '80:80'
    volumes:
       - ./app:/root/app
       - ./dev.conf:/etc/apache2/sites-available/dev.conf
       - ./entrypoint.sh:/entrypoint.sh
    entrypoint: ./entrypoint.sh
    environment:
        APACHE_RUN_DIR: /var/run/apache2
        DOTNET_CLI_HOME: /tmp
        DOTNET_USER_SECRETS_FALLBACK_DIR: ./secretTest
```

You can see at the bottom I have added the environment variable and defined it like the error has described. I made sure the folder exists. However, I still get this error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How are you ensuring the directory exists?  (Do you `RUN mkdir` in the Dockerfile?  Or have you `docker-compose run kestrel_apache ls -l` to look?)

Comment: I go to my windows file explorer and I manually right clicked and created a new folder named secretTest. EDIT: Wow i think I realized my mistake...the folder needs to exist within the linux container right?....not my local desktop file directory...I will try this

Comment: That did not work. I changed the dir to '/secretTest' instead of './secretTest' and added 'RUN mkdir /secretTest' to my docker file. I also just tried changing the path to /tmp which for sure exists and I still get the same error

Comment: Similar problem, I have a need to set this on Linux, not Docker, and have set this environment variable but it still fails with this error. This is in a published deployment I need to set to Development for some diagnostics but without .NET SDK available, only runtime.

Comment: Try to run application with "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Production", problem should disappear, as not user secrets should be loaded in production mode.